# Is it possible to write select, which will retrieve all functions including count,avg,sum etc?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to print a list of all functions. Also their parameters. Is it possible for functions which are build in like count or sum in Oracle SQL?

I tried several select like:

- select distinct procedure_name from all_procedures where object_name = 'STANDARD' order by procedure_name;
- SELECT * FROM all_procedures where procedure_name like 'SUM';
- select listagg(data_type, ',') within group (order by position) from all_arguments where object_name = 'SUM' group by overload;
  But nothing good came from them.

Comment: No. Those are SQL functions, and `all_procedures`, etc. would only show stored PL/SQL routines. SQL is one thing, PL/SQL is another. You'd have to look in the documentation for the SQL language and the arguments its functions and operators take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific dynamic views or another table to list aggregate functions. To see aggregate functions, their syntax and descriptions, you can use the official Oracle documentation: [SQL Language Reference - Aggregate Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848)

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of functions and procedures use: select * from all_arguments (that is if you do not have access to sys.dba_arguments). That will show you the function/procedure names, packages they are found in (if they are in package), owner and the order of their arguments and the types of arguments. Argument with position 0 is the return value for functions.
There is no way to know when a function is aggregate function or window function.